# C++ check if any of the previous 5 or next 5 elements equal a value

Tags: c++

Is there an easy way to do this without a for loop or lots of ifs and elses.

So for example..

```
for (i=0;i<arr.size;i++) 
    if (any of the values from i-5 to i+5, ignoring i = value) 
    {
        // Do stuff ...
    }
```

Do I need set a nested loop from -5 to +5. Or can I used `std::any_of`  perhaps

Comment: Same value or any value?

Comment: Value will be set, so if any of them equal 10

Comment: does `value` change during the outer `for` loop?

Comment: As evident from your question title, if the `value` to be compared is same, you can use nested `for` loops.

Comment: So, you are searching for a pattern of: 5x value, 1x not value, 5x value in a sequence of length size, with value being an argument, right? Should be an O(n) algorithm, easy.

Comment: No sorry I am looking at whether any of the values from i-5 to -i+5 are equal to 2. Nested loops should work but I wasn't sure if there was some sort of useful range function this.

Comment: @user3189899 is `arr` sorted?

Comment: Shall the conditional code only execute for the first, once for any, or once for each viable position?

Comment: No. It contains 400 elements

Comment: Each array element would be checked against the previous 5 and next 5 elements. Please ignore the obvious out of bounds issue, I think I can handle that.

Comment: do the elements have to be processed in order

Comment: ehm, you said a position i is viable if any of arr[i-5] to arr[i-1] or arr[i+1] to arr[i+5] equals parameter value. Why check the element at i?

Comment: If I've read it correctly then there's an efficiency saving you can make since you are sequentially passing through `arr` and you know the result of the last check (i.e whether `value` was in `i-5` to `i+5`, except `i`) so all you'd need to check is `arr[i]` and `arr[i+5]` for each new iteration. I know I'm simplifying things here (boundary cases etc.) but that would be far faster than unnecessarily checking 10/11 elements per `arr` iteration wouldn't it?

Comment: No sorry someone edited my code. I-5 to i+5 - I just didn't want to check if i=10

Comment: What does it mean to say `arr[i-5]` if `i < 5`? What does it mean to say `arr[i+5]` if `i >= (arr.size - 5)`?

Comment: To loop based on current index i through i-5 to i+5 to analyse adjacent data

Comment: Don't forget to accept an answer if one solves your problem.

Answer (score 5):

Despite on how the description may look, the complexity is **linear** since the inner loop (if any) iterates a constant number of times (and does not depend on the number of the data).

Since you suggest your data have an array form (contiguous and randomly indexable) and using nested loops is in fact the easyest and most straightorward way to benefit of all optimization capabilities and processor caching. Whatever "dynamically sorted" container sill perform poorly, due to the distributed nature of the data.

I will most likely do

```
for(size_t i=5; i<N-5-1; ++i)
{
    int good=0; //will count the successful comparisons
    for(size_t j=i-5; j<=i+5; ++j) 
    {
        if(i==j) continue; //skip the i on i case
        if(array[j]==value) ++good;
    }
    if(good==10) do_stuff(i);
}
```

The inner loop executes entirely on cached data (and does not depend on N, so it does not contribute in the complexity). With nowadays CPU works probably faster tan trying to sort somehow the data in set-like container (with non contiguous storage).

Despite on the elegance of many begin/end approach, the old KISS indexing wins.

You can parametrize the `array[j]==value` predicate as well as the `5` (and 10 == 2*5) with no cost (a template function will be inlined), making this even more general.

if you don't want to branch the inner loop, you can even make it faster with

```
for(size_t i=5; i<N-5-1; ++i)
{
    int good=0; //will count the successful comparisons
    for(size_t j=i-5; j<i; ++j) good+=(array[j]==value);
    for(size_t j=i+1; j<=i+5; ++j) good+=(array[j]==value);
    if(good==10) do_stuff(i);
}
```

Where the 11 elements loop is split in two halves (avoiding to check for j==i) and the increment on `good` is "computed" functionally, with no branches. This will also lead to faster execution on predictive piping processors.

---

**EDIT**

Looks like I misunderstood that only one equal value is enough (not all).

If that's the case, you can check for `good!=0`, but you can even short-cut:

```
for(size_t i=5; i<N-5-1; ++i)
{
    bool good=false; //will count the successful comparisons
    for(size_t j=i-5; j<i && !good; ++j) good|=(array[j]==value);
    for(size_t j=i+1; j<=i+5  && !good; ++j) good|=(array[j]==value);
    if(good) do_stuff(i);
}
```

This will break the loops as soon a match is found, but makes the loop no more unrollable. 
Removing `&& !good` will not cut off the loops, but may be running them till the end is faster than checking to cut or not.

If you shortcut cut the loops, you can use `=` instead of `|=`, if you don't shortcut, using a bool has no advantage: `|=` by a compiler stand point is more complicated than `+=`

Comment: This looks good but the aim was to find out if any of the values equal ten rather than all of them.

Comment: I suppose if good was !=0 I would have my answer or I could use a bool

Comment: also comparisons of i=0 to arr[400]-[395] and i=400 to arr[0]-arr[4] would not work with this solution.

Comment: @user3189899: about using a bool see my edit.

About the limits, sorry: It should have been `i<N-5-1`so that if N=400, `i` goes from 5 to 393, so j can go from 0 to 4 as a minimum and from 394 to 399.  I coorect.

Comment: Suppose N =400 here. This loops from 5 to 393, how would validation of array elements 0-4 occur? Also this seems to return a value of 0 for j in practise?

Comment: The problem look impossible for whatever N<11: if you state that you have to compare 5 number before, you must HAVE 5 numbers before. and element 0..4 don't. (just like element 395..399 don't have after). That's just my interpretation.

Comment: ... Feel free to adjust the bounds as you need: i=[0..N], j=[(min(0,i-5)..i) and (i..min(i+5,N-1)].  But will not perform as before, since the bounds are not anymore fixed.

Comment: OK, so I need to make the array circular to consider the 5 before 0 as 400,399,398,397,396.

Comment: Refine the question or post another one... Otherwise question and answers will no more match

Comment: OK. I did state in OP that i=0 and I need to access i-5. Is it possible to size_t j=i-5; j<i; j++ to correlate to arr[399,398,387,396,395]

Answer (score 2):

In terms of **readability**, I prefer the doubled `for` loops.

In terms of **performance**, I would use the following which runs the **minimal** `n+5` iterations (for scope = 5) **without additional data structures**.
All in all **`O(n)`** complexity and **`O(1)`** memory.

```
void checkArray(int arr[], int n, int value) {
    const int scope = 5;

    int closestBeforeI = -1;
    int closestAfterI = -1;

    for (int i = 0; i < scope && i < n; ++i) {
        if (arr[i] == value) {
            closestAfterI = i;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        if (closestAfterI == i) {   // exclude self index
            closestAfterI = -1;
        }
        if (closestAfterI == -1 && i + scope < n // closest after not set & i + scope is within range
                && arr[i + scope] == value) {
            closestAfterI = i + scope;
        }

        if (closestBeforeI != -1 && closestBeforeI + scope >= i
                || closestAfterI != -1) {
            do_stuff(i);
        }

        if (arr[i] == value) {
            closestBeforeI = i;
        }
    }
}
```

worked fine for this main:

```
int main()
{
    const int n = 14;
    int arr[] = {1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2};
    int value = 2;
    // should be true for indices: 0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12

    checkArray(arr, n, value);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an efficient approach that uses previous results to run in O(n) time. Works for both stl containers and built-in arrays and is circular.

```
#include <vector>
#include <functional>
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

template <class Indexable, class EQComparable>
void for_each_if_value_in_neighbors(Indexable& container, 
                                    const EQComparable& value, 
                                    size_t offset, 
                                    std::function<void(size_t)> callable)
{
    size_t size = std::distance(std::begin(container), std::end(container));

    size_t next_index = offset % size;
    size_t prev_index = size - (offset % size);

    size_t range_count = 
        std::count(std::begin(container) + prev_index, std::end(container), value) +
        std::count(std::begin(container), std::begin(container) + next_index, value);


    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i) 
    {

        bool found_cur = (container[i] == value);
        bool found_next = (container[next_index] == value);

        range_count += found_next - found_cur;

        if (range_count)
        {
            callable(i);
        }

        bool found_prev = (container[prev_index] == value);

        range_count += found_cur - found_prev;

        next_index = (next_index + 1) % size;
        prev_index = (prev_index + 1) % size; 
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> vec = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0};
    for_each_if_value_in_neighbors(vec, 2, 5, 
        [&](size_t i){ std::cout << i << " vector check\n"; });

    // prints:  0 vector check
    //          1 vector check
    //          2 vector check
    //          8 vector check
    //          9 vector check
    //          10 vector check
    //          11 vector check
    //          12 vector check
    //          14 vector check
    //          15 vector check

    int arr[] = {2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2};
    for_each_if_value_in_range(arr, 2, 5, 
        [&](size_t i){ std::cout << i << " array check\n"; });

    // prints:  0 array check
    //          1 array check
    //          2 array check
    //          3 array check
    //          4 array check
    //          5 array check
    //          10 array check
    //          11 array check
    //          12 array check
    //          13 array check
    //          14 array check
    //          15 array check

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
template<class C, class V, class F>
void customrunner(C&& c, V&& v, F&& f) {
    auto it = begin(c);
    unsigned viable = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        viable <<= 1;
        if(it != end(c)) {
            viable |= *it == v;
            ++it;
        }
    }
    for(auto i2 = begin(c); i2 != end(c); ++i2) {
        if(viable & 0x3bf)
            f(c, i2);
        viable = (viable<<1) & 0x7ff;
        if(it != end(c)) {
            viable |= *it == v;
            ++it;
        }
    }
}
```

The above would do as you said you want, iterating the sequence exactly twice (Once for testing, twice for providing an iterator to pass).

If you really want an index instead of an iterator, that's left as an exercise for the reader.

Answer (score 1):

You could probably use `std::any_of`, but then you'd have to
exclude the value you're at (or it will match), which would
probably require two calls to `std::any_of`.  I'd probably just
use `std::count_if`:

```
if ( std::count_if( arr.cbegin() + std::max( 0, i - 5 ),
                    arr.cbegin() + std::min( arr.size(), i + 5 ), 
                    [&]( int x ) { return x == arr[i] } )
        > 1 ) {
    //  ...
}
```

The use of `std::max` and `std::min` is to ensure that you don't
go out of bounds.  Alternatively, you could start at `begin()
+ 5`, and end at `end() - 5` (after ensuring that the array had
at least 10 elements), and not worry about it.  In fact, if you
do that:

```
for ( auto it = arr.cbegin() + 5, end = arr.cend() - 5; it != end; ++ it ) {
    if ( std::count_if( it - 5, it + 5, []( int x ) { return x == *it; } ) > 1 ) {
        //  ...
    }
}
```

Just be sure that the array is big enough first.

Comment: well the end suggestion (and code) does not process the first and last 5 items, so it's really a solution to an easier problem than the OP's `for (i=0;i<arr.size;i++)`.

Comment: I feel obliged to point out that if `i` is unsigned and `i < 5`, then `i - 5` will produce a very large number and `std::max(0, i - 5)` will not produce the expected result.

Comment: @Alf The end solution is easier.  But he didn't actually say what he wanted to do in such limit cases.

Comment: @MatthieuM. But why would it be unsigned?  Unsigned is only for bit manipulations; it would be very poor programming practice to use it for an index.

Comment: @JamesKanze: I generally use unsigned for indexes because a negative index does not make sense. Since `size_t` is unsigned, and therefore `std::string::size_type` is unsigned, it seems I am not the only one with this opinion.

Comment: @MatthieuM. Just listen to yourself. You're using a type that would be problematic here, complicate things, by your own assessment. And on that basis you say that it makes more sense. That's irrational.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: I am not saying it makes sense *here*, I am saying that in general using an unsigned type makes sense for indexing (because negative indexes do not make sense) but that here the formula presented would break with unsigned indexes and that therefore it should be mentioned in the answer that it only works with signed ones.

Comment: @MatthieuM. The problem is that unsigned types don't behave correctly, mathematically.  If you're more interested in the bits than the numerical value, use unsigned.  But if the numerical value has any signification (and it does with indexes), then avoid the unsigned types.

Answer (score 1):

This is more big-O efficient when the window size can vary (not just a fixed +/- 5 offset).

For the fixed small window size in this question it’s probably much less efficient than a simple sequential scan, such as using `count_if` as in James’ answer.

```
int const   array[] =
{3, 1, 4, 1, 5, 9, 2, 6, 5, 3, 5, 8, 9, 7, 9, 3, 2, 3, 8, 4, 6, 2, 6, 4};

multiset<int>  numbers;
for( int i = -5;  i < count_of( array );  ++i )
{
    if( i > 5 ) { remove_one( array[i - 6], numbers ); }
    if( i + 5 < count_of( array ) ) { numbers.insert( array[i + 5] ); }

    if( i >= 0 )
    {
        int const value = array[i];
        if( numbers.count( value ) > 1 )
        {
            cout << "a[" << i << "] = " << value << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Helper functions:

```
template< class Item, Size n >
auto count_of( Item (&)[n] ) -> Size { return n; }

void remove_one( int const v, multiset<int>& s )
{
    auto const it  = s.find( v );
    if( it != s.end() ) { s.erase( it ); }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use segment tree for this type of problem and complexity will much less.