# C++ check of this condition in O(nlog(n)) time?

Tags: c++, math, language-agnostic

Suppose you have a *sorted* vector {x<sub>i</sub>}<sub>i=1</sub><sup>n</sup> whose elements are all positive and contain no tie (=no two elements in this vector are the same).

I'm looking for the smartest way to check that:

2x<sub>i</sub> - x<sub>j</sub> - x<sub>k</sub> != 0 for all 1 <= i != j != k <= n.

I have a hunch that this could be done in time O(nlog n), or otherwise in better than naive time, perhaps using a strategy similar to what is developed in the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25866339/c-check-if-any-of-the-previous-5-or-next-5-elements-equal-a-value).

Recall that the entries of x are all positive and sorted so the entries of x_k+k_j are sorted as well.

P.S. Im looking for algorithmic/language agnostic ideas. The c++ tag is mainly there
in case doing this requires taking advantage of some smart caching strategy.

## Edit:

@liori makes a good point below, that finding the pair (j,k) for a given i is O(n), using an algorithm similar to what is done [in the last iteration of this answer to a related question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/38994/finding-pair-of-sum-in-sorted-array/38996#38996). The issue here is IMO whether it is possible to combine these many O(n) steps more efficiently than naively. For example, we can find the pair (j,k) for a given index i in time O(n). But do we need to consider again *all* the  the entries j'<=j
and k'<=k as candidates for the following index i'=i+1? Does these savings somehow add up?

Comment: Did I accidentally roll back a good edit by adding the P.S.? If so I apologize

Comment: Yes, but I added it again, no worries :-) The SO system leaves a bit to be desired regarding concurrent edits

Comment: Do you expect those **!=** to be transitive?

Comment: @jxh: yes: these are always for three different indexes i,j,k (it is not necessary to check the other cases since there are no ties in the vector)

Comment: @jxh: if i=k, then 2x_i = x_i + x_j, therefore x_i = x_j. As there are no ties, this forces i=j. So, it doesn't matter.

Comment: Quadratic time is certainly possible. I wonder if it can be done faster though…

Comment: I believe the quadratic solution does not use the fact that the entries of the vector are sorted.

Comment: It does, at least the algorithm i have in mind. Let me write it down as an answer…

Comment: @liori: There's a paper by Baran, Demaine, and Patrascu that gets something like an O(n^2/log^2 n) bound for 3SUM in a weird model of computation allowing some limited parallelism (word RAM).  Doubt you can do better.

Comment: You have two O(n^2) answers, one that uses O(n^2) space and one that uses O(1) space. I think you put the checkmark on the wrong one.

Comment: @MarkRansom: indeed good catch. Plus the c++ code is a recursive one. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quadratic time is possible with an algorithm as follows:

For every i∈{1, …, N}:

1. Let `j=i-1, k=i+1`.
2. If `j<1` or `k>N`, stop.
3. Compute `d=(x_i - x_j) - (x_k - x_i)`
4. If `d=0`, stop.
5. If `d<0`, `j--`.
6. If `d>0`, `k++`.
7. Repeat from step 2.

This algorithm uses the fact that x_i must have a value that is equally as far from x_j (the `x_i - x_j` expression) as it is from x_k (`x_k - x_i`). Also, given the vector is sorted, the differences increase with increase in difference between indices.

Comment: here is why I think nlog(n) is possible: http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/write-a-c-program-that-given-a-set-a-of-n-numbers-and-another-number-x-determines-whether-or-not-there-exist-two-elements-in-s-whose-sum-is-exactly-x/

Comment: @user189035: The algorithm/code you are referring to is searching a known sum, but in your case the sum if unknown. So you cannot possibly determine which way to shrink.

Comment: @Abhijit: I wonder whether once a pair (j,k) has been found for a given $i$, whether that tells us anything about the new pair (j',k') for the next index i'=i+1 since x(i')>x(i). This is essence is my question.

Comment: I wouldn't trust that site, I don't see how the first algorithm is logarithmic… with an array [0, 2, 4, …, 2N] when looking for 2N-1 (which is impossible to find there), it clearly does linear number of steps.

Comment: @liori: I agree. However, the O(n) solution (for each i) you propose is also offered here: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/38996. The question now is, can we combine these O(n) bricks better than naively if we have to solve it for several index i given that the x_i are sorted. (Again, I wouldn't have though of this formulation of the question without your answer)

Comment: @user189035: Given the data is already sorted, to find the pair for a given sum, it is an O(n) complexity. Now to apply this algorithm for each of the numbers in the vector as the sum, the complexity would be O(n^2)

Comment: @Abhijit: I agree with the first part (the O(n)) but I hope we can do better than the second part of your comment. If we know that i=i+1 implies 2x(i')>2x(i), do we need to consider all the entries j'<j and k'<k? How does this plays out for i''=i+2? Im not sure this is clearly formulated. This is really a question from someone with <1k rep to someone with >20k rep (I hope the brievity of my comments doesn t overshadow this).

Comment: Do you really think reputation means something for this kind of question?

Comment: @JaviV: even then, I don t want my comment to sound brash or arrogant but merely hopeful/optimistic.

Comment: @user189035: TBH, I can't think of any easy way of reusing computations between iterations. Integers are tricky beasts with problems like subset sum being in NP…

Comment: @liori: I will let the question float a bit. I wasn't expecting such a fast answer actually. I really need to do more research myself.

Answer (score 4):

Note that "sorted" doesn't help you, since comparison-based sorting can sort any list of n numbers in O(n log n) time.

I can't quite prove [3SUM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3SUM)-[completeness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_%28complexity%29) for this problem, but [this paper by Jeff Erickson](http://cjtcs.cs.uchicago.edu/articles/1999/8/contents.html) proves that, in a restricted model of computation, no subquadratic algorithm for your problem exists.  This is not quite an impossibility proof, but the model of computation Erickson uses allows all of the reasonable tricks I can think of.  In particular, I doubt that anyone on this site is going to come up with an O(n log n) algorithm for your problem in the near future.

It may interest you that, in some models of computation permitting limited parallelism, there exists a subquadratic algorithm for 3SUM.  I believe that [this paper by Baran, Demaine, and Patrascu](http://www.mit.edu/~ibaran/papers/3sum.pdf) was the first to show this.

Answer (score 2):

This is another Ο(n<sup>2</sup>) algorithm. A hash table is populated with the sums and corresponding pairs. Since you specified [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b), the following code has array indices starting from 0 instead of 1 as in your problem statement:

```
typedef std::pair<int, int> xy;
typedef std::unordered_map<int, xy> sums;

template <int N>
xy func (const int (&a)[N]) {
    sums s(2*N*N);
    for (int lo = 0; lo < N-2; ++lo) {
        for (int hi = lo+2; hi < N; ++hi) {
            int ss = a[lo] + a[hi];
            if (ss % 2 == 0) s[ss] = xy(lo, hi);
        }
    }
    for (int i = 1; i < N-1; ++i) {
        if (s.find(2*a[i]) != s.end()) return s[2*a[i]];
    }
    return xy(0, 0);
}
```

This algorithm explicitly illustrates the search space for the sums is Ο(n<sup>2</sup>).

You are thinking you can get to a sub-quadratic algorithm by finding a sub-linear algorithm to determine if a given  *x<sub>i</sub>* is matched to a pair (*x<sub>j</sub>*, *x<sub>k</sub>*). **Instead, rethink the problem as determining if a given pair (*x<sub>j</sub>*, *x<sub>k</sub>*) is matched to an *x<sub>i</sub>*.** If you consider it that way, it should be more clear to you that a worst case quadratic algorithm is required to determine that no pair satisfies your property.